# Replace url pattern text with valid html inside text

Tags: angularjs

I am outputting some array of messages via `ng-repeat` (jade syntax)

```
ul
    li(ng-repeat="m in messages") {{m.text}}
```

There may be url in the message, but since I am using ng-repeat, the url will be outputed as text.
How do I replace some part of message containing url link to actual **clickable** link in result?

For example message is

```
"Take a look at http://www.example.com/example.png"
```

It should be replaced as

```
"Take a look at <a href="http://www.example.com/example.png" target="_blank">this link</a>"
```

And it should be replaced automaticaly for each message in `ng-repeat` block.

Comment: You will propably be best off by writing your own directive which takes your message as an input, finds the URL (e.g. with RegEx) and renders the message in your desired format.

Answer (score 0):

define two custom filters

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('getlast', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var msgArray = input.split(' ');
    return msgArray.pop();
  };
});

app.filter('removelast', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.substr(0, input.lastIndexOf(" "));
  };
});
```

Your template

```
<li ng-repeat="m in messages">
  {{m.text | removelast}}
  <a href="{{m.text | getlast}}">{{m.text | getlast}}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Read my question one more time, replacing whole message as a link was not a case.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I assume that the link is always at the end.